# MySQL Administration issue

Tags: administration, mysql

We have a MySQL database that is set up on one of our servers.  We have been using the MySQL Administrator 1.2.12 program to manage the databases on the server.  This server was set up and configured by a person who is no longer with the organization.

I am trying to create a new schema in the MySQL server.  I have logged in as Administrator and when I select the option 'Create new Schema' I get an error message:  **"MySQL Error Number 1044 Access denied for user 'Administrator'@'%' to database TAtest"**

I have run the SHOW GRANTS command and get the following information:

```
'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD *9C9F3367144B''
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `TRACSBACK`.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tmp`.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mysql`.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `JMSTEST`.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `interlock`.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `JMS`.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `HADEN`.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `empvoting`.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `CVCLEANUP`.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `i\_schema`.* TO 'Administrator'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION'
```

When I look at the user table I don't know that these were properly set up either....

```
HOST                       User
%                          Administrator
%                          hbowling
%                          kserna
%                          landrews
%                          root
%                          rtarefeder
10.8.8.107                 root
inftch5.domain.name        hbowling
inftch5.domain.name        root
localhost                  hbowling
localhost                  root
domain.name                hbowling
metroweb.domain.name       root
```

where domain.name is a valid domain name.

I get the error and can not create a new schema if I am logged in as Administrator, root or myself.

I tried downloading the MySQL Workbench 5.0.30 OSS Community Edition which, as far as I can tell from the information on the web, should connect to my MySQL server, but it doesn't: see http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ says Database Administration (replacing MySQL Administrator, which is what I have been using).  However when I go to the help section of the community version of MySQL Workbench it says you have to have the Commercial version in order to get server connections.

So 2 issues - 
How can I get my existing MySQL Administrator to allow a user to which I have access to create a new schema?
Is there a version of the MySQL Workbench that is free that will allow me to connect to my database server the way the MySQL Administrator does?

Comment: Why don't you reset the root password and use that to manage the privileges ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the new database using with root .

But if you want to  create a database with Administrator user id,

from your script there is no access for the "TAtest".

Provide the privileges for that database , den only server will allow the Administrator to create the database/tables.
OR
        GRANT all *.* to Administrator@'%' identified by 'pwd'; 
        ( Now Administrator id can create n num of databases ).